# WCF WebService with UserName Authentication test on SoapUI

Tags: wcf, authentication, soapui

I have WCF WebService with UserName Authentication and not able to test it with SoapUI.

Here you have web.config:

```
<behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="FHPBusinessLogicService.ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceCredentials type="FHPBusinessLogicService.Security.PasswordServiceCredentials, FHPBusinessLogicService">
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" />
          </serviceCredentials>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="Custom" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ServiceConf" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" >
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="65536" maxArrayLength="65536" maxBytesPerRead="65536" />
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential"  >
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName"  />
            
          </security>
         
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

On SoapUI i'm receiving:

> An error occurred when verifying security for the message

I'm testing it on my local machine, local IIS 7 server.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 22):

In the 'Request Properties' in SoapUI in section 'Wss-Password Type' just select option '**PasswordText**'. That will do the thing

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add WS-Security Configuration to your request.
Read this http://www.soapui.org/SOAP-and-WSDL/applying-ws-security.html

And see the section under "Username". And then in your testsuite in soapUI, be sure to add the ws-security conf you just created. That worked for me.

Comment: I don't know what a "keystore file" is. Why does the article assume that I do, and that I have one ready to use? **edit** I can now see that there's a link at the top of the page that covers this.

Answer (score 0):

The other "dumb" thing that could be causing this error is that you left the `Username` field blank in your `Auth`... even if your `Service` doesn't care about the `Username`, you still need to provide some value there.